# String Compare mismatch in java

Tags: java

Hello I am having a some difficulty with a very simple program.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Compare
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
         String username;
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         String users[] = {"John", "James", "Smith", "Paul"};

         System.out.println("Please Enter Username: ");
         username = input.next();

         for( int i = 0; i < users.length(); i ++ )
         {
               if( users[i] == username )
                  System.out.println("Match");
               else
                  System.out.println("No Match");
         }
    }
}
```

When I run this program I get No Match which I don't know how is possible when I enter the same string as on of the strings in the users array. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .equals method to compare strings ( and any other objects ) not == operator. 
for instance:

```
users[i].equals(username);
```

== operator used with reference variables checks if they are pointing at the same spot in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `users[i].equals(username)`.

`==` uses reference, not value comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
if (users[i].equals(username))
```

Don't use == to compare Strings in Java, because it determines whether two Strings are the exact same object in memory; whereas `equals` actually compares the characters in the Strings.

Comment: ****it. You beat me by one second.

Comment: @Paul, it's not a competition.  And actually, I think you beat ME by one second.

Comment: you're right. I got it mixed around. Curse retracted.